# How to add image and text together without overflow on the toolbar

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I have mat-tab and I want to put weather information which I get from accuweather API.My toolbar is responsive and flex.Those images are getting small when page size changed.That works fine but when I want to add temperature info under the image,overflow is happening and looks very bad.How can I make those temperature numbers under the image without any overflow.

**Actual**
[image]
**Expected**
[image]
**Reality**
[image]
Here what I tried below

```
        <li>
           <div class="d-flex">
                   <div *ngFor="let dailyForecast of dailyForecasts">
           <img class="responsive" src="{{appConfig.weatherIconsPath}}{{dailyForecast.Night.Icon}}.png">       
<small>{{dailyForecast.Temperature.Minimum.Value}}°C /                                               
{{dailyForecast.Temperature.Maximum.Value}}°C</small>
             </div>                                                                                             
             </div>    
        </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a max width for the image using CSS:

```
img.responsive {
max-width: 40px;
}
```

Comment: That makes fit over there in toolbar but ,makes ring bell upper

Comment: Can you send us a link to where the issue appears?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```html
<li>
  <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
    <div *ngFor="let dailyForecast of dailyForecasts" 
         class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
      <img class="responsive" src="{{appConfig.weatherIconsPath}}{{dailyForecast.Night.Icon}}.png">
      <small>{{dailyForecast.Temperature.Minimum.Value}}°C / {{dailyForecast.Temperature.Maximum.Value}}°C</small>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Note: without an actual [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) I can't help you more.